# ASP.NET MVC Displaying and automatically refreshing a progress bar for donations

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax, progress-bar

I am building a simple ASP.NET MVC site to record and track donations. We have a set goal of $2,500,000 and will be entering donations into a database as they come in. We need to have a meter or progress bar on the homepage to show how close they are to the goal. Right now I have a partialView that has the donationGoal and the totalDonationAmount as decimals. What can I use to display this as a bar and automatically refresh at set intervals? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate % and display something like http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/ and refresh it with javascript (`setInterval()`).